# Different terms for different indexes in one request,

Tags: elasticsearch

it is possible to get in one _search request elements for 2 different indexes with 2 different terms?
i.e. 
for index index_1 terms are:
lang: pl
bool: false

for index index_2 terms are:
lang: en
bool: true

And i want one response with records. If not, how to achieve consolidation from responses from multi indexes with _msearch?
i.e. from index_1 i have 1000 records with _score from 10 to 100 and from index_2 i have 10 records with _score from 50 to 90, and i need it sorted by _score.
Sorry for my english.
Hope you understand me :)
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can target index in your query, using a term on index:
"terms": {
                  "_index": [
                    "indexA",
                    "indexB"
                  ]
                }

This work like any bool query.

For example:

POST http://IP:9200/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                      *******
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "_index": [
                    "indexA",
                    "indexB"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                       *************
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "_index": [
                    "indexC",
                    "indexD"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

for your second question, you have to look for score function.

Comment: Big thanks, :) i've modified it a bit, and works like a charm.